# Angular lazy load module that only contains services?

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-lazyloading

I'm looking for a way to lazy load a module that doesn't contains any components but services only. The background: in my app is an Excel export service using `exceljs` library. This library is extremely large and I'm trying to prevent that the library will become part of `vendor.js` or `main.js`. It is "included" via `import * as Excel from 'exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js'` in a service.

Now I have several components in separate modules that make use of the "Excel export" service (no component). I would prefer a method that the service is only loaded if the user is "clicking the export button" but not before.

How this can be done?

Comment: Have you tried adding your service to a module and then load the module with `import(path/to/module).then(...)` ?

Comment: @AndreiGătej where and how should I put this piece of code. Please can you give a bit extended example?

Comment: @AndreiGătej ok now I understood what you wrote with import(...). But the question is: how can I get access of a variable from the imported files, like ìmport { exceljs } from 'pathtoexceljs.min.js`?

Comment: I’ll provide an example a bit later. But until then, here’s my reasoning: you have a service which imports that excel lib(which is large). You’d then create a module in which you will only import this service. Then, for example, when a button is clicked, in the handler you’d have ‘import(path-to-excel-module).then()...’. In the then’s callback you should be able to compile the module or something like that, I haven’t done this in a while, but I’m sure you can access the module’s imports from there

Comment: Thank you so much! Currently, I was able to load a JS file (CDN https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/exceljs/4.1.1/exceljs.min.js). But I'm unable (I don't now how) to access variables or functions. Without this "lacy load" I do: import Excel from 'exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js' and later const wb = new Excel.Workbook(); But in the "lacy mode" I have no idea how I can access "Excel" because it is always undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Here would be an approach:

#### excel.module.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [ExcelService]
})
export class ExcelModule {
  static loaded = false;
}
```

#### app.component.ts

```js
export class AppComponent {
  constructor (
    private compiler: Compiler,
    private injector: Injector
  ) { }
  
  load () {
    import('./excel/excel.module')
      .then(m => m.ExcelModule)
      .then(m => {
        console.dir(m.loaded)
        
        return m;
      })
      .then(m => this.compiler.compileModuleAsync(m).then(r => (m.loaded = true,r)))
      .then(factory => {
        const module = factory.create(this.injector);
        
        console.dir(module.injector.get(ExcelService))
      })
  }
}
```

The first time is loaded, `m.loaded` will be `false`. On subsequent times, it will be `true`. With this, we can be sure that we don't load the module multiple times.

Of course, a easier (and probably better) approach will be to have a dedicated service for loading modules e.g `ModuleLoaderService`, where you'd have a `Map` object keeping track of loaded modules.

[ng-run demo](https://ng-run.com/edit/SmdTZdSHHAyrrpEPM1Hl?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts).